# SharedPreferences does not work - getString always returns the default value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem with SharedPreferences in Android.

This is my code:

```
    SharedPreferences s = this.getSharedPreferences("kurs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    s.edit().putString("eur", "1.80");
    s.edit().commit();
    SharedPreferences a = this.getSharedPreferences("kurs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String kurs = a.getString("eur","7");

    Toast hhh= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),kurs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    hhh.show();
```

I´m setting the String and want to read it out directly after that in the onCreate method. But i always get the specified default value "7".

What was wrong? I already researched for that problem, but i can´t found helpful things.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You call edit twice .. try s.edit().putString("eur", "1.80").commit(); and remove the extra s.edit() below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each time you call "s.edit()" a new editor is created.  Thus your "commit()" call is on an instance of the editor that has not had your setting applied.  Try this:

```
SharedPreferences s = this.getSharedPreferences("kurs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
Editor editor = s.edit();
editor.putString("eur", "1.80");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try my code below. What i think is wrong in your code, that you are using different "Editor" instances here:

> "s.edit().putString("eur", "1.80");"

and here

> s.edit().commit();

```
private static String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "MyAppID";
// Write the value
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
prefsEditor.putString("KEY", "VALUE");
prefsEditor.commit();
// Get the value
return getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("KEY", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("kurs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit(); 
editor.putString("eur", "1.80");
// commit the edits 
editor.commit();


SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
String kurs = myPrefs.getString("eur", "7");

Toast hhh= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),kurs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
hhh.show();
```

Try This